# Keep CSS triangle angle on responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, trigonometry

Here is the JS fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/L83gzqnf/5/

What I want is the opposite angle to always be 45 degrees, and the width to always be 66.6%. Therefore, the height needs to be dynamically adjustable, based on the width.

I have:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var height = document.getElementById(".tri").height();
    var width = document.getElementById(".tri").width();

    document.getElementById(".tri").style.border-top = (width / tan(45));
});
```

As you can see I can use trig to calculate the height, but the function is not working?!

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a resize function as well as a load function

Comment: ...oh and aren't the height and width both 0?

Comment: ...and one more....`.tri` is a class...not an ID.

Comment: If you inspect the div, they're both 500px.

Comment: `fiddle.jshell.net/:58 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Comment: but the CSS height/width are stated as 0...perhaps you meant Computed height

Comment: Yeah computed height.

Answer (score 0):

If I have read your question correctly, this fiddle should be what you're after: https://jsfiddle.net/qkmzp1jj/

What I have done is:

1. Create a new function that gets the window width *(note: not the width of the element)*;
2. calculates what 2/3 of that width is; and
3. then applies the border-widths for the two sides.

This function is then referenced in the `document.(ready)` function for on page load and the `window.(resize)` function for when the window is resized (such as  a mobile user rotating their device).

Answer (score 0):

The changes I did:

1. jQuery Selectors
2. use `outerWidth()` and `outerHeight()` instead of `width()` and `height()`
3. change the css in jQuery style
4. add `Math.` to `tan()`
5. changed class to id

The `width()` and `height()` functions return 0 because you set it to 0 in your CSS. `outerWidth()` and `outerHeight()` will return the expected value.
Also you have to add a onResize eventHandler to react on a window resize.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var height = $("#tri").outerHeight();
  var width = $("#tri").outerWidth();
  $("#tri").css("border-top", (width / Math.tan(45)) + "px solid black");
});
```

```css
#tri {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 500px solid black;
  border-right: 500px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tri"></div>
```